# RouteComponentProps from react-router-dom with custom properties

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

I have a component called Navbar which uses the location object from history, as defined in RouteComponentProps.

I tried to add a custom prop to my component like so:

```js
interface IProps{
   title?: string
}

class Navbar extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}> & IProps>{

}
```

While this does not throw an error, when I try to do:

```
<Navbar title="My Custom Page Title" />
```

Typescript complains with:

Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, never> | (Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, never> & { ...; }), any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Readonly<...>)'.
Property 'title' does not exist on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, never> | (Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, never> & { ...; }), any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Readonly<...>)'.ts(2322)

Originally, I had tried this:

```
interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps{
   title?: string
}
```

But I also get a typescript error.

I am not sure what the correct method is for extending or expanding RouteComponentProps.

Comment: When you call it with just the prop `title`, typescript doesn't know about the props which will get injected by the router, so you're getting that error because you haven't supplied the required props from `RouteComponentProps`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste but if I am using  RouteComponentProps<{}> why wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be withRouter being set up like this:

```
export default withRouter<IProps, any>(Navbar);
```

I am not sure what to put in any, as the docs say StaticContext (for server side rendering), but putting any works for now. The main point is IProps needs to be defined in withRouter as the first argument.